# Read specific object from json as stream using JsonTextReader or any other alternative

Tags: c#, json, stream, json.net, large-data

Have to read large file as a part of JSON from HTTP Post to Web API.
As File itself is the part of JSON.
example:

```
{
"type": "xxxx",
//other JSON,
 "attachment": {
    "mimetype": "text/csv",
    "extension": "csv",
    "data":{a,b,c,d,f}
}
```

I have to only look for attachment object but again "data" here contains large file. Can be csv, pdf, JSON or image and most important will be of big size > 1GB.

As per analysis able to read this by these wrappers

```
public class AttachmentParser 
             : JsonParser<Attachment>
{
    public AttachmentParser(Stream json, string jsonPropertyName)
        : base(json, jsonPropertyName)
    {
        Parse();
    }

    public override void Build(Attachment parsable, JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.Value.Equals("extension"))
        {
            reader.Read();
            parsable.Extention = (string)reader.Value;
        }
        else if (reader.Value.Equals("data"))
        {
            reader.Read();
            parsable.Data = reader.Value;
        }
    }

    protected override bool IsBuilt(Attachment parsable, JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        var isBuilt = parsable.Extention != null && parsable.Data != null;
        return isBuilt || base.IsBuilt(parsable, reader);
    }

    private static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Json Parser:

```
 public abstract class JsonParser<TParsable>
    where TParsable : class, new()
{
    private readonly Stream json;
    private readonly string jsonPropertyName;

    protected JsonParser(Stream json, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        this.json = json;
        this.jsonPropertyName = jsonPropertyName;

        Result = new TParsable();
    }

    public TParsable Result { get; private set; }

    public abstract void Build(TParsable parsable, JsonTextReader reader);

    protected virtual bool IsBuilt(TParsable parsable, JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        return reader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.None);
    }

    protected void Parse()
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(json))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                do
                {
                    jsonReader.Read();
                    if (jsonReader.Value == null || !jsonReader.Value.Equals(jsonPropertyName))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var parsable = new TParsable();

                    do
                    {
                        jsonReader.r;
                    }
                    while (!jsonReader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.PropertyName) && !jsonReader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.None));

                    do
                    {
                        Build(parsable, jsonReader);
                        jsonReader.Read();
                    }
                    while (!IsBuilt(parsable, jsonReader));

                    Result = parsable;
                }
                while (!jsonReader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.None));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:
Here JSONTextReader have jsonReader.Read() method which does read in element by element but by default read as the object. Which will be in memory and increase more load to the memory during this operation.
Had looked at the overloads does not contain ReadAsStream method.

Is there any way to read large data as stream via different library or same library  in different way (no overload available though)